# How to create a prepared statement in PHP with a formula involving columns in the where clause?

Tags: php, variables, bind, prepared-statement

I want to create prepared stmt such as

```
"SELECT id,latitude,longitude 
FROM sometable WHERE 
(3437.74677 * ACOS(SIN(latitude_radians) * SIN(?) + 
COS(latitude_radians)*COS(?) * COS(longitude_radians - ?))) <=  ?";
```

in PHP. `Where` clause is a function of column values and bind variables
but how should I bind the values. Or is this even  a legal prepared stmt?

Thanks in advance,
-v-

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is: Have you already tried binding the variables but it didn't work (error message?) or are you asking as to try it for you instead of doing it yourself?

Comment: Hm, looks like a perfectly valid prepared PDO statement to me. Just curious: isn't this Haversine? If so, are you aware that you're using nautic miles there?^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem here.

See:
[PHP Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Extremely minimal sample:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $QUERY );
$stmt->execute( $arguments_array )
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being unclear.
As I understand following is an example of PHP prepared stmt,

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['name'])))
```

Now the where clause is always a simple, `column = ? AND column2 = ?`. In my case though its function and it didnt work when assigned values to the bind variables. I will regenerate the error again and post it. 
I was wondering then if it is even legal to have a function of column names and bind variables in the where clause.